# Do any offline forms of documentation exist?

Tags: jquery, documentation

I'm not going to have access to wifi or internet for a bit and I'd like to develop during that time.  Is there a resource of local documentation for PHP, jQuery, javascript, etc?

Comment: You mean "stand-alone", not "portable". You could buy books...

Comment: "When I was your age, television was called books." (Seriously though, this is a good question. +1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/download-docs.php

http://www.jqapi.com/jqapi-latest.zip

http://github.com/downloads/erikzaadi/jqapi/jQAPI-1.6.air?v=05182011